# how is context maintained in angular dom

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

consider the below DOM

```
<div ng-controller="A">
  <button ng-click="sayHello()">SayHello</button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="B">
  <button ng-click="sayHello()">SayHello</button>
</div>


A(){
   var sayHello() = function(){
     console.log("Hello")
   }
}
B(){
   var sayHello() = function(){
     console.log("Hello")
   }
}
```

Say we have 2 controllers A and B each of them have `sayHello()` method.

- How is the context of the function maintained?
- How does angular know which function to call?
- How can the same be achieved with native javascript?

**EDIT 1**
- How can associate context to DOM

```
<script>
  var module = {
    namspace: {}
  }
  var module.namspace.object1 = {}
  var module.namspace.object1.someFunction = function(){}
  var module.namspace.object2 = {}
  var module.namspace.object2.someFunction = function(){}
</script>
<div context="module.namspace">
    <div context="object1">
        <button id="button1" onClick="someFunction()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div context="object2">
        <button id="button2" onClick="someFunction()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the expected behaviour is:

1. when i click `#button1` `module.namspace.object1.someFunction` needs to get called
2. when i click `#button2` `module.namspace.object2.someFunction` needs to get called

Answer (score 2):

It's the role and the particularity of angular, the `controller` define a particular `scope` and use only code declared on this `scope`.

Same thing with the namespace. He only do `A.sayHello()` if the method exist he execute else error. He have not to differentiate them.

You can't define a particular scope in your HTML with JavaScript but you can use namespace and create same `functions`/`var` name.

```js
var A = {}; // namespace A
 A.sayHello= function (){
  alert("A hello");
 }; 


var B = {}; // namespace B
 B.sayHello= function (){
  alert("B hello");
 };
```

```html
<div onclick="A.sayHello()">
  A
</div>
<div onclick="B.sayHello()">
  B
</div>
```